# Cannot plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote the code below, but when I run the code I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

n = 10

aa = [float(i) for i in range(1, n)]
a = np.squeeze(np.asarray(range(1, n)))
bb = -0.8*np.exp(-a/1.4) + 1.4*np.exp(-a/2.0) + 0.4*np.exp(-a/3.0)
b = np.squeeze(np.asarray(bb))

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(a, b)# I used different combinations of a, aa, bb and b. None of them worked.
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the import line to be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: I cannot believe that I didn't notice that! It's time to sleep!